# Install MovableType under Nginx on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, installation, nginx

I want to try MovableType (and I do not want to install Apache).

I took a clean Ubuntu Server 9.10 instance, and did something along these lines:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mysql mysqlclient
$ sudo apt-get install movabletype
$ sudo apt-get install nginx
```

Now I see that I have to tell nginx to look at /usr/lib/cgi-bin/movabletype/.

But nginx does not support pure CGI scripts, and I've got a feeling that MovableType would want some custom configuration anyway.

I failed to find any good docs on how to pair MT with nginx. Are there any? A config file example would be perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add additional fastcgi parameters in nginx config:

   fastcgi_param    PERL5LIB $document_root/mt/lib;
   fastcgi_param    MT_HOME $document_root/mt;
   fastcgi_param    MT_CONFIG $document_root/mt/mt-config.cgi;
2. Use CGI wrapper from http://nginx.localdomain.pl/wiki/FcgiWrap